# How to add two IPv6 dns-nameservers into /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: dns, ipv6, resolvconf

With IPv4, I can add two DNS Name Servers without any problem, like this:

```
"dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8"
```

Then on my resolv.conf I got:

```
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

BUT, it does not work for IPv6, only the first IPv6 DNS Server appear at my resolv.conf, look:

```
"dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888"
```

But then, my resolv.conf remain only with the first one:

```
   nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Apparently, Ubuntu (resolvconf / ifupdown) is ignoring the second DNS Name Server, so, how to fix it?!

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2800:210:0:4::2
        netmask 64
        gateway 2800:210:0:4::1
        dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

Comment: You seem to have found a bug. I'd file a report at launchpad.

Answer (score 4):

There can be only three nameservers in resolv.conf. If you remove one of the IPv4 nameservers the second IPv6 nameserver will be added.

Comment: Is this a limitation of the implementation, or is this actually following some specification?  Looks like you'd have to change MAXNS in resolv.h and recompile. Unless there are special v6 rules.

Comment: @ThiagoCMC let us know if this fixes it (and if it does, you can checkmark this to accept it as the answer).

Comment: Also relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28004/how-to-overcome-libc-resolver-limitation-of-maximum-3-nameservers. It mentions >3 name servers, possible increased timeouts and running a local DNS cache instead of adding more name servers.

Answer (score 3):

I was initially thinking this was a bug, but I'm going to assume @Sander's answer is correct here.  I'm not sure if resolvconf uses resolv.h or something else for the maximum nameserver value, though.

Generally, instead of using resolv.conf, Here are a couple things to try:

You could try editing dhclient.conf as suggested in the [Google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) :

`prepend domain-name-servers 2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844;`

For this method on Ubuntu, I believe the current path is `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

The same document gives instructions for using NetworkManager.  If you use that, you can right-click on your network icon, find your connection then select "Edit", then go to the IPv6 tab.  You can set "additional DNS servers" there.

Answer (score 2):

Add it manual to the /etc/resolv.conf

```
 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844

 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

Comment: No, I can't add it manually, resolv.conf have: "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN"

Comment: @maythux  sadly (in my opinion), editing resolv.conf is deprecated....  However, this can be used as a test.  You won't break anything.

Comment: @belacqua Yeah sure sadly...

Comment: So, this is a BUG, right?!

Comment: @ThiagoCMC no it's not but editing manual was deprecated

Comment: this is not always a good idea: "Add it manual to the /etc/resolv.conf" because it violates modern systemd-resolved based systems. 
like it or not: systemd-resolved is a new layer in between. If it applies to your Linux. 


So this is probably not a bug - systemd-resolved works different in modern OS like ubuntu 19.xx. 

a nice recap is found here:  

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved#DNS

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/  tells you what the background is and why it is different today. Like it or not ....

Answer (score 2):

@ThiagoCMC said "No, I can't add it manually, resolv.conf ... ":   Yes, you are right - but you can force the system NOT to change this file: edit it and (as root) chattr +i resolv.conf  then it can never be edited again by scripts. Unfortunately from that moment on you have to maintain it yourself, always ...

Comment: Ubuntu 19.xx actively checks for the link character of resolv.conf in some DNS related tasks. Not finding a link makes some processes fail.  

>> do avoid this brute force solution!

Answer (score 0):

Although MAXNS is set, resolvconf can add as many NS's as you like by using /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d

In there you will find 'head' which contains the warning message found at the top of /etc/resolv.conf and a (probably empty) file called 'base'.

You can edit these files freehand to add additional lines in resolv.conf (such as 'nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx').

Whether or not adding >MAXNS lines will actually work is a different matter but that's how to force custom content into the resolv.conf itself.